# Android Table layout Column alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I am populating a table layout with a user names list programmatically. I don't know how many user ll be display because its dynamic. But I have to show them in a tablelayout each column should have length exactly the name length but its not doing like this, Problme is with column it expand  base on name length. If first name is a long name then it expand all the below column to same length as well is there any way each cell ll stretch exactly to its own length.Let suppose first row first  column is (example name)   then second row first column you can see also stretching to length of (example name)

1. | example name | xyz |
2. | abc          | def |
3. | ab           | g   |

   I need some thing like this

| example name | xyz |

| abc| def |

| ab | g |

Comment: Then what is the problem ?

Comment: I am unable to do this . Every column stretched to the biggest column lenght. I want to shrink it to by its content. I Hope I clear you to some extent

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a separate table for each row.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>example name</td>
        <td>xyz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>def</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ab</td>
        <td>g</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: any other solution it ll be complex and ll be costly I need to draw it again and again... on serach filter... kindly let me know if is there anyother solution

Comment: Can you use div instead of table?

Comment: abdul basit i am talking about android